# Firebase recyclerView

Tags: firebase, recyclerview

tengo un recyclerView que de momento me muestra unos datos pero ahora quiero cambiarlo esos datos por otros (titulo y foto), la cuestion es que tengo de por medio un array y no tengo ni idea de como empezar, dejo el codigo y la base de datos:

De los events de cada usuario tiene que coger como mínimo el titulo si se puede coger tb el foto mejor que mejor

En el codigo muestro como saco los eventos

[image: BBDD]

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View vista=inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false );

    FirebaseDatabase database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    eventos = new ArrayList<>();


    recyclerView = vista.findViewById( R.id.rv_gallery );

    final Context context = this.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    FirebaseUser userAut;
    userAut = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();


    database.getReference("Users").child(userAut.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent( new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                User lista=dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                eventos=lista.getevents() ;// en debug lo recibe bien
                adapter=new AdapterGallery( eventos );
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager( new LinearLayoutManager( context ) );
                recyclerView.setAdapter( adapter );

        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    } );



    return vista;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El *quid*  de la cuestión está aquí: `adapter=new AdapterGallery( eventos );`. Tú estás pasando los datos a la clase `AdapterGallery` la cual debe tener los getter necesarios para mostrarte el título o la foto que requieres. O, si esa clase te sirve para otros usos, deberás implementar otro adaptador diferente y usarlo en este caso.

Comment: Tengo la clase Event con los metodos get y set para poner el titulo foto y demas que sale en la imagen de la bbdd. La cuestion es que creo que tengo que hacer un for o un if y decirle que si lo que hay en el array de Users events coincide con Events code que lo añada, creo que van por ahi los tiros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo he podido sacar, este es el codigo.

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
List<String> eventos;
List<String> eventosUser;
AdapterGallery adapter;
FirebaseDatabase database,databases;
int i;



public GalleryFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View vista=inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false );

    database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databases=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    eventos = new ArrayList<>();
    eventosUser = new ArrayList<>();


    recyclerView = vista.findViewById( R.id.rv_gallery );

    final Context context = this.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    FirebaseUser userAut;
    userAut = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    database.getReference("Users").child(userAut.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent( new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            User lista=dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            eventos=lista.getevents();
            for( i=0; i<lista.getevents().size();i++){
                databases.getReference("Events").child( eventos.get( i ) ).addListenerForSingleValueEvent( new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        Event event=dataSnapshot.getValue(Event.class);
                       // eventosUser= event.getTitle() ;

                        eventosUser.add(event.getTitle());
                        adapter=new AdapterGallery( eventosUser );
                        recyclerView.setLayoutManager( new LinearLayoutManager( context ) );
                        recyclerView.setAdapter( adapter );

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                } );
        }
}
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
    return vista;
```

}
}